# onSubmit doesn't want to set state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to build a form using Material-UI. My TextField needs to collect information from the user and on submit my handleSubmit() function should set the state to what the user entered. At the moment it doesn't. I have tried to use 'onChange' instead of 'onSubmit'. This approach allowed me to save the information however the UI started to misbehave, allowing the user to enter only one letter into the TextField. I'm puzzled. I'd really appreciate some suggestions. Please see my code below:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import { withStyles, makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import './Navbar.css';
import * as AiIcons from "react-icons/ai";


class StackO extends Component {

    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
          state_foo: null,
        }
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this)
      }

      handleSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault();

        this.setState({ 
            state_foo: e.target.value,
         });

      }

      showstate = event => {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log(this.state.state_foo)
      }

      render() {

        const CssTextField = withStyles({
            root: {
                '& label.Mui-focused': {
                color: 'green',
                },
                '& .MuiInput-underline:hover:before': {
                borderBottomColor: 'white',
                },
                '& .MuiInput-underline:before': {
                borderBottomColor: 'white',
                },
                '& .MuiInput-underline:after': {
                borderBottomColor: 'green',
                },
            },
            })(TextField);
        
          
        const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
            margin: {
                margin: theme.spacing(4),
            },
        }));


        return (
            <>
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <div>
                        <div className={useStyles.margin}>
                            <Grid container spacing={1} alignItems="flex-end">
                                <Grid item>
                                    <AiIcons.AiOutlineForm />
                                </Grid>
                                <Grid item>
                                    <CssTextField className={useStyles.root}
                                    value={this.state.state_foo}
                                    style ={{width: '125%'}}
                                    inputProps={{ style: { fontFamily: 'Arial', color: 'white'}}}
                                    id="input-with-icon-grid" label="Proposed term"
                                    InputLabelProps={{style: { color: 'white'}}}
                                    />
                                </Grid>
                            </Grid>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <button type='submit' onClick={this.showstate}>Submit</button>
                </form>
            </>

        )
      }

}

export default StackO
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be seeing the following warning in your console:

```
Warning: You provided a `value` prop to a form field without an `onChange` handler. This will render a read-only field. If the field should be mutable use `defaultValue`. Otherwise, set either `onChange` or `readOnly`.
```

You're currently telling your `input` to read its value from `this.state.state_foo`, but you're never updating that state. To fix this, pass an `onChange` handler to your input:

```
...
handleChange(e) {
  this.setState({ state_foo: e.target.value });
}

...

render() {
  ...
  <input value={this.state.state_foo} onChange={this.handleChange} />
  ...
}
```

The other way to do this would be to leave the input uncontrolled and only read the state from the submit event, but the "react-way" is to manage the state yourself.

You were probably only able to add one character to the input at a time because you were preventing the default behavior.

Side note: I'd be weary to put the `withStyles` and `makeStyles` code in the `render` method of your class; consider moving this out of your render, as to not cause unnecessary UI bugs.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply :) What was causing the issue was combination of both. So, when I added 'onChange' I ended up having UI misbehaving again allowing user only to input one character at the time. This has changed though after moving both 'withStyles' and 'makeStyles' out of render.